# useEffect hook not getting called in child component on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have below simple code.
The basic idea here is -

FormContainer component loads the data and passes on to child component Form.

The all rendering is handled by Form.

Whreas submit action handling and loading the pre-filled data is done from FormContainer

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";


const loadedState = {
    firstName:'Atul',
    lastName:'Joshi',
    fruits:'mango',
    isGoing:true
}


const initialState = {
    firstName:'',
    lastName:'',
    fruits:'',
    isGoing:false
}

const FormContainer = () => {

    const [userData,setUserData] = useState(initialState);

    const onSubmitHandler = formState =>{
        console.log(formState);
    }

    const loadData = () =>{
        console.log('setting user Dta',loadedState);
        setUserData(loadedState)
    }

    return(
        <Fragment>
            <Form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler} data={userData}></Form>
            <button type="button" onClick={loadData}>Load Data</button>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

const Form = ({onSubmit,data}) => {

    const [formState,setFormState] = useState(initialState);

    useEffect(() => {  
        console.log('form state with data ',data); // this is not called once reset button is clicked 
        setFormState(data)
    },[data]);


    const onChange = e => {
        console.log(e.target.name);
        console.log(e.target.value);
        console.log(e.target.type);
        const value = e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;
        setFormState({
            ...formState,
            [e.target.name]:value
        })
    }

    const onSubmitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('formState = ',formState)
        onSubmit(formState);
    }

    const init = e =>{
        console.log('init..')
        setFormState(initialState)
    }


    return(  
        <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
           <span>{`Your name Is - ${formState.firstName} ${formState.lastName}`}</span>
           <label htmlFor="firstName">FirstName</label>
           <input id="firstName" name="firstName" onChange={onChange}
           value={formState.firstName}/>

           <label htmlFor="lastName">LastName</label>
           <input id="lastName" name="lastName" onChange={onChange}
           value={formState.lastName}/>
           <label htmlFor="fruits">Fruits</label>
           <select id="fruits" name="fruits" value={formState.fruits} onChange={onChange}>
                <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
                <option value="lime">Lime</option>
                <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
                <option value="mango">Mango</option>
           </select>

           <label htmlFor="isGoing">
                Is going:
                <input
                    name="isGoing"
                    type="checkbox" 
                    checked={formState.isGoing}
                    onChange={onChange}/>
                </label>
           <button type="submit" onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>Submit</button>
           <button type="button" onClick={init}>Reset</button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default FormContainer;
```

The issue I am facing is :

When Load Data button is clicked initially ,the default values get populated in the form.

But once clear Data is called , then sub sequent calls to Load Data button is not loading any data in the form.

That is : console.log('form state with data ',data) statement from Form component is not called

Can anybody please let me know what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately found an answer to this

I had to use below code in `loadData` function in `FormContainer` component ,
because as long as the data passed to child component `Form` is a new object , the `useEffect` will be called definitely

Earlier same `loadedState` object was passed to `Form` component and `useEffect` was not getting called

```
const loadData = () =>{
    console.log('setting user Dta',loadedState);
    const newLoadedState = {...loadedState};
    setUserData(newLoadedState)
}
```